# Please add the tag "foreign-language"

Tags: feature-request

I just asked a question, and it's about the usage of non English words in English ( [What should be the plural of “kibbutz”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95995/what-should-be-the-plural-of-kibbutz) ).

In my opnion the tag [foreign-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/foreign-language) is relevant for the question, however it doesn't exist. Since I don't have enough reputation to add a new tag, I'm asking the community to add this tag, so that I and others could use it.

Comment: What would that tag be used for? A similar tag might be [loan words](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words), which covers foreign words adopted into English. Does this tag work, or do you have something else in mind for scope?

Comment: [tag:loan-words] works fine, I wasn't aware of its existence.

Comment: And it's worth pointing out (in case you didn't know, and for others in the future) that a -1 on Meta simply indicates someone disagreed with the proposal.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I'm aware of this, and of the fact that it doesn't affect the reputation of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having read through your question, as well as a similar one on how to [pluralize Japanese import nouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501/should-nouns-borrowed-from-japanese-be-pluralized), I think the tag you are looking for would be [loan-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loan-words).

So, I don't think a new tag is really needed.

Comment: We already have far, far too many. They're useless, I'm afraid.